# sql server running total with over, partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to calculate running total in following query

```
select 
    a.ICode, MONTH(a.VDate), YEAR(a.vdate)
    , sum(isnull(a.qty, 0))
    , sum(isnull(a.qty, 0)) OVER (partition by a.icode order by a.icode) AS 'total' 
from 
    t_Stock as a
group by 
    a.ICode, MONTH(a.VDate), YEAR(a.vdate)
order by 
    a.icode, YEAR(a.vdate), MONTH(a.VDate)
```

but I am getting an error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Column 't_Stock.Qty' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Why does '`t_Stock.Qty`' needs to be in `GROUP BY` clause as I am already using aggregate function `(Sum(a.Qty))` ?

Some demo data :

```
icode   vtype   qty   vdate 
32114   Sales   -2    2013-06-03 18:09:17.953 
33459   Sales   -1    2013-06-03 19:39:59.843 
34446   Sales   -1    2013-06-03 20:46:17.030 
39914   Tra     -3    2014-01-07 13:02:31.000
30899   Sales   -1    2013-06-04 11:48:06.267 
25676   Sales   -3    2013-06-04 17:34:01.470 
32126   Sales   -1    2013-06-04 18:12:44.267 
34688   Sales   -1    2013-06-04 18:40:52.750 
31550   Sales   -1    2013-06-04 19:26:40.937 
32795   Sales   -1    2013-06-05 12:03:00.250
```

Comment: @M.Ali , I have selected answers which really solved the issue, Rest I did not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using window functions with aggregation, you actually need to nest the results.  Here is a version of your query that should work:

```
select a.ICode, MONTH(a.VDate), YEAR(a.vdate),
       sum(isnull(a.qty, 0)),
       sum(sum(isnull(a.qty, 0))) OVER (partition by a.icode order by a.icode) AS total
from t_Stock a
group by a.ICode, MONTH(a.VDate), YEAR(a.vdate)
order by a.icode, YEAR(a.vdate), MONTH(a.VDate);
```

I'm not sure what you intend to do with this.  Having the `order by` contain the same value as the `partition by` is unusual.  I would expect something like this:

```
select a.ICode, MONTH(a.VDate), YEAR(a.vdate),
       sum(isnull(a.qty, 0)),
       sum(sum(isnull(a.qty, 0))) OVER (partition by a.icode
                                        order by year(a.vdate), month(a.vdate)
                                       ) AS total
from t_Stock a
group by a.ICode, MONTH(a.VDate), YEAR(a.vdate)
order by a.icode, YEAR(a.vdate), MONTH(a.VDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

write as:

```
select a.ICode,MONTH(a.VDate), YEAR(a.vdate)
, sum(isnull(a.qty,0)) OVER(partition by a.icode order by a.icode)
  AS 'Runningtotal'
, sum(isnull(a.qty,0)) OVER(partition by a.icode,MONTH(a.VDate), YEAR(a.vdate) 
  order by a.icode,YEAR(a.vdate),MONTH(a.VDate)) AS 'total' 
from 
t_Stock as a
--group by a.ICode ,MONTH(a.VDate), YEAR(a.vdate)
order by a.icode,YEAR(a.vdate),MONTH(a.VDate)
```

Comment: i tried this query before, it takes a lot of time in executing.

Comment: please post some data from your table t_Stock it would be easier to explain as of why two window functions are required to get these totals

Comment: This also won't get the same results - assuming there are multiple rows in `t_stock`, you version will retain them, while the (attempt at the) original will not.  @NitinKabra - At least part of the speed problem is that `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` are probably forcing a table scan (removes use of any index for getting `VDate`).  Yes, please get us starting data and desired results.

Comment: i have copied few rows in the question. Sorry for the format of table.

Comment: ok ..specify what do you mean by running total is like for a given month and year you want to have total of qty for qualifying iCodes??because the second window function which is giving error is actually working on groups created in Groupby and not on individual rows of t_Stock table

Answer (score 1):

*why does 't_Stock.Qty' needs to be in GROUP BY clause as I am already using aggregate function (Sum(a.Qty)) ?*

this issue appears because u use "SUM(something)" then u use "SUM(something) over(partition by...)"
when u use "SUM(something)" then you will need the "group by ..." clause
but when u use "SUM(something) over(partition by...)", it doesn't accept/need a "group by.." clause
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

choose one between them.

if you want to use both of them, try below query:

```
select a.ICode,MONTH(a.VDate) as 'month', YEAR(a.vdate) as 'year'
, bb.xtotal
,sum(isnull(a.qty,0)) OVER (partition by a.icode order by a.icode) AS 'total' 
from 
@temp a
inner join
(
 select b.ICode, b.vdate,
    sum(isnull(b.qty,0)) as xtotal
 from @temp b 
 group by b.Icode, b.vdate
) bb on a.Icode = bb.Icode and bb.vdate = a.vdate
order by a.icode,YEAR(a.vdate),MONTH(a.VDate)
```