# left join and show all rows from left table and null if not exist on right table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i have two tables

1) m_Year which contains month and year as :

```
month   year   
5       2013   
6       2013   
7       2013   
8       2013   
9       2013   
10      2013
```

2) stock table which contains itemcode, month, year, stock as :

```
itemcode  month   year  stock 
AG1       5       2013  20
AG1       7       2013  10
AG1       9       2013  5
AG1       10      2013  20
```

result should be like :

```
itemcode  month   year  stock 
AG1       5       2013  20
AG1       6       2013  null
AG1       7       2013  10    
AG1       8       2013  null
AG1       9       2013  5
AG1       10      2013  20
```

following is the query i am using :

```
select a.ICode, MONTH(a.VDate) as month, YEAR(a.vdate) as year,
   sum(isnull(a.qty, 0)) as stock       
from t_Stock a left join m_year as b on month(a.vdate) = b.month and year(a.vdate)= b.year
group by a.ICode, MONTH(a.VDate), YEAR(a.vdate)
order by a.icode, YEAR(a.vdate), MONTH(a.VDate);
```

which produces following result :

```
itemcode  month   year  stock 
AG1       5       2013  20
AG1       7       2013  10
AG1       9       2013  5
AG1       10      2013  20
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to do?  You seem to be asking [multiple questions related to this dataset/query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443555/sql-server-running-total-with-over-partition/23444341#23444341) - what overall problem are you facing?

Comment: I am trying to generate monthly stock report. Previous question helped me get the monthly stock my running total, but it is missing data from the month where there is no transaction of that particular item. So I created a table with month and year to join it, and hence this question.

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one code, you need to generate all the rows first, using a `cross join`, and then use `left outer join` to get the data:

```
select sic.ICode, MONTH(y.VDate) as [month], YEAR(y.vdate) as [year],
       sum(s.qty) as stock       
from m_year y cross join
     (select distinct s.ICode from stock) sic left outer join
    t_Stock s 
    on month(s.vdate) = y.month and year(s.vdate)= y.year and
       s.Icode = sic.Icode
group by sic.ICode, MONTH(y.VDate), YEAR(y.vdate)
order by sic.ICode, MONTH(y.VDate), YEAR(y.vdate);
```

Note that the aggregation and select columns come from the tables int he `cross join`, not the `t_stock` table.  When the `left outer join` fails, these columns will have a `NULL` value, which is not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65d6a/6)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE m_Year (month INT, year INT)

INSERT INTO m_Year  VALUES
(5 ,      2013),   
(6 ,      2013),   
(7 ,      2013), 
(8 ,      2013),   
(9 ,      2013),   
(10,      2013)


CREATE TABLE stock (itemcode VARCHAR(10),  month INT,year INT,  stock INT)
INSERT INTO Stock VALUES
('AG1',       5 ,      2013,  20),
('AG1',       7 ,      2013,  10),
('AG1',       9 ,      2013,  5),
('AG1',       10,      2013,  20)
```

**Query 1**:

```
select ISNULL(a.itemcode,'AG1') AS ItemCode 
      ,b.MONTH                  AS month
      ,b.YEAR                   AS year
      ,ISNULL(sum(a.stock), 0)  AS stock       
from  m_year as b  left join Stock a
on a.month = b.month and a.year = b.year
group by  a.itemcode
         ,b.MONTH     
         ,b.YEAR
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65d6a/6/0)**:

```
| ITEMCODE | MONTH | YEAR | STOCK |
|----------|-------|------|-------|
|      AG1 |     6 | 2013 |     0 |
|      AG1 |     8 | 2013 |     0 |
|      AG1 |     5 | 2013 |    20 |
|      AG1 |     7 | 2013 |    10 |
|      AG1 |     9 | 2013 |     5 |
|      AG1 |    10 | 2013 |    20 |
```